# I have downloaded telegram open source code from GitHub

Tags: android, java-native-interface, telegram

Build command failed.

```
Error while executing process /Users/nyame/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.1.6352462/ndk-build with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=/Users/nyame/Documents/androidProjects/Telegram-FOSS/TMessagesProj/jni/Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=/Users/nyame/Documents/androidProjects/Telegram-FOSS/TMessagesProj/jni/Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-16 NDK_OUT=/Users/nyame/Documents/androidProjects/Telegram-FOSS/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/afatDebug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=/Users/nyame/Documents/androidProjects/Telegram-FOSS/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/afatDebug/lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-16 --jobs=16 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
Android NDK: ERROR:/Users/nyame/Documents/androidProjects/Telegram-FOSS/TMessagesProj/jni/Android.mk:avutil: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file    
Android NDK: Check that /Users/nyame/Documents/androidProjects/Telegram-FOSS/TMessagesProj/jni/./ffmpeg/build/armv7-a/lib/libavutil.a exists  or that its path is correct   

fcntl(): Bad file descriptor
/Users/nyame/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.1.6352462/build/core/prebuilt-library.mk:45: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
```

These are the steps I have tried but not working for me:

1. git submodule update --init --recursive in the libtgvoip folder
2. research but it looks my problem is different.

This is my android.mk file and it seems it cannot file path to libavutil.a file

```
MY_LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
LOCAL_PATH := $(MY_LOCAL_PATH)

LOCAL_MODULE    := avutil 

LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS := true

ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi-v7a)
    FFMPEG_INCLUDE_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/ffmpeg/build/armv7-a/include
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ./ffmpeg/build/armv7-a/lib/libavutil.a
else ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),arm64-v8a)
    FFMPEG_INCLUDE_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/ffmpeg/build/arm64-v8a/include
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ./ffmpeg/build/arm64-v8a/lib/libavutil.a
else ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),x86)
    FFMPEG_INCLUDE_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/ffmpeg/build/i686/include
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ./ffmpeg/build/i686/lib/libavutil.a
else ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),x86_64)
    FFMPEG_INCLUDE_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/ffmpeg/build/x86_64/include
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ./ffmpeg/build/x86_64/lib/libavutil.a
endif

......
```

Answer (score 0):

Telegram source uses some code with native languages like (C and C++) so android studio gradle needs NDK (native development kit) for build project, i think you don't have NKD on your system.

Comment: I have download NDK on my system but still not working

Comment: I have downloaded NDK tool on my system and the path has been configured in the android studio too.

Comment: Did you do all Compilation Guide that they tell in github url ?

Comment: [link](https://github.com/Telegram-FOSS-Team/Telegram-FOSS/tree/master)


this is where i downloaded the telegram open source code and now I checked the guide to cloning and now I have downloaded it again using `git clone --recursive https://github.com/Telegram-FOSS-Team/Telegram-FOSS.git
` but I am having this error 
**
ninja: error: '/Users/nyame/Documents/andela/Telegram-FOSS/TMessagesProj/jni/ffmpeg/build/armeabi-v7a/lib/libswscale.a
**